# Communicating between classes in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a Typescript program the contains multiple classes. In this application each instance requires all these classes. These classes also need to communicate with one another. For example:

```js
class A{
  someNumber: number = 10;    
}

class B{
  otherNumber: number = 20;
  doSomething() {
    //check someNumber from class A
    if(someOtherNumber === 10) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I came up with the following solution: Wrap the classes in a parent class then pass a reference to parent.

```js
class Parent{
  classA: A;
  classB: B;
  constructor(){
    this.classA = new A(this);
    this.classB = new B(this);
  }

}

class B{
  otherNumber: number = 20;
  parent: Parent;
  constructor(parent: Parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  doSomething() {
    //check someNumber from class A
    if(this.parent.classA.someOtherNumber === 10) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this goal? or is there a better solution?

Comment: why use classes at all if you're not gonna use encapsulation

Comment: this is a very simple example to demonstrate what I need to do with the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Passing around a simple plain object instead of a fake `Parent` class would be simpler and more intuitive:

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }
export const instances = {
  a: new A(),
  b: new B()
};
```

```
// other files:
import { instances } from './instances';
// use instance.a, instance.b
```

But it's a bit weird to define a class that's only used once. Using plain objects for `a` and `b` might make things even cleaner.

```
export const a = {
  someNumber: 10,
};
export const b = {
  someNumber: 20,
  doSomething() {
    // ...
  }
};
// or export them together in a single object
```

Comment: I think I need to clarify a bit more: 
These classes will not be used only once, rather, they will be part of another class that holds more information and will have many instances. but I do not want to pass a reference to main class because it contains many information that these classes will not need. With that in mind, is creating a plain object inside the main class still better than a parent class inside the main class? Or should I just pass a reference to our main class even though it will pass unneeded info?